# Merge Sort does not work properly. The numbers in array are not sorted

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

The following is my code for Merge Sort in JAVA, but the output is not expected.

given input is [49, 1, 3, 200, 2, 4, 70, 5]

The output is :

Merge sort : [2, 4, 49, 1, 3, 70, 5, 200]

Which the number is not sorted. I believe the problem is in the merge method. Can anyone help?

merge_sort method:

```
private static int[] merge_sort(int[] unsorted_array) {
        
        if (unsorted_array.length < 2) {
            return unsorted_array;
        }
        
        int mid = unsorted_array.length / 2;
        
        int[] first_array = new int[mid];
        int[] second_array = new int[unsorted_array.length - mid];
        
        //Copy element to first and second array.
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i ++) {
            
            first_array[i] = unsorted_array[i];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < second_array.length; i++) {
            
            second_array[i] = unsorted_array[mid + i];
        }
        
        merge_sort(first_array);
        merge_sort(second_array);
        
        int[] sorted_array = merge(first_array, second_array);
        
        return sorted_array;
    }
```

merge method:

```
private static int[] merge(int[] first_array, int[] second_array) {
        int[] result = new int[first_array.length + second_array.length];
        
        int index_result = 0;
        int index_first = 0;
        int index_second = 0;
        
        while (index_first < first_array.length && index_second < second_array.length) {
            
            if (first_array[index_first] < second_array[index_second]) {
                
                result[index_result] = first_array[index_first];
                index_first++;      
            } else {
                
                result[index_result] = second_array[index_second];
                index_second++;
            }
            
            index_result++;
        }
        
        while (index_first < first_array.length) {
            
            result[index_result] = first_array[index_first];
            index_result++;
            index_first++;
        }
        
        while (index_second < second_array.length) {
            
            result[index_result] = second_array[index_second];
            index_result++;
            index_second++;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: What's the input for the given output...?

Comment: Please post the `main` as well as the method that calls the `merge` method. As far as i can tell, the merge method looks good.

Comment: Btw. what is your input to the method? If I recall correctly, both `first_array` and `second_array` have to be sorted for it to produce a sorted output.

Comment: Hopefully it helps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Comment: Merge sort algorithm is recursive, your method is not

Comment: I have added merge_sort method which is returning the sorted array. And the input is an integer array [49, 1, 3, 200, 2, 4, 70, 5].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a very simple mistake.

Those two following lines are wrong in your code:

```
merge_sort(first_array);
merge_sort(second_array);
```

You should write those two lines as follows:

```
first_array = merge_sort(first_array);
second_array = merge_sort(second_array);
```

cause, your **merge_sort()** method **returns** a **sorted array**. It does not sort in place the **unsorted_array** parameter. Rather, it returns the sorted elements in a newly created **sorted_array**. So, you would get the sorted result from return value of **merge_sort()** method and then, you should merge them. Rather than doing that, you were just merging two unsorted arrays.

Its not necessary, but you could write as follows for clarification:

```
int[] sorted_first_array = merge_sort(first_array);
int[] sorted_second_array = merge_sort(second_array);
// and then merge
int[] sorted_array = merge(sorted_first_array, sorted_second_array);
// then return
return sorted_array;
```

[P.S.]: When you are coding in java, please use java variable and method naming convention. Its easier to read code when you're following convention.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the sorted intermediate results to merge, instead using the original splitted arrays. Modify your code as below:

```
first_array = merge_sort(first_array);
second_array = merge_sort(second_array);
        
int[] sorted_array = merge(first_array, second_array);
```

Also you don't need to create these intermediate arrays. You just have to pass the low, high pointers to your array to indicate the portions of the array you are sorting and merging.

Like :

```
private static void merge_sort(int[] unsorted_array, int low, int high) {
        
   if (low == high) return;
                    
   int mid = low + ( high - low ) / 2;
        
   merge_sort(unsorted_array, low, mid);
   merge_sort(unsorted_array, mid+1, high);
        
   merge(unsorted_array, low, mid, high);

}
```

where `high` is inclusive and you call this like : `merge_sort(arr, 0, arr.length-1)`